# Why use Electron with SPA frameworks?

Tags: reactjs, angular, vue.js, electron, single-page-application

Because I want to develop an Electron app, I searched quite a lot of Electron tutorials.
Most of tutorials are using Electron with React or Vue.js (or few of Angular). I'm curious about that why SPA frameworks are almost essential for Electron app development.

Answer (score 6):

- If you don't model your application as an SPA then the only alternative is causing the built-in Chromium browser engine to reload a separate HTML document when your user navigates to a different "area" in your application.

  - And don't even think about using `<frameset>`!
- Reloading a separate HTML document is jarring to users because:

  - It resets the page state, so you need to reinitialize your page's JavaScript and DOM state if necessary - which is wasted effort if it's state that doesn't change between pages (e.g. user information).
  - Reloading HTML causes a massive re-layout operation which causes a blinding flash of white light for a couple of frames, which is unpleasant if a user is in Dark Mode or similar.
  - And whole UI reloads are *not* part of the typical desktop application user-experience: application UIs are not "documents" in the way that HTML was originally designed to be.
- That said, you don't need to use a specific SPA framework - you could always use only your own code, but HTML and JavaScript don't have a built-in UI platform, framework and widget set (the relatively recent "Web Components" spec is more of a foundation for a UI platform rather than a framework in itself - and HTML has only a very anemic set of built-in widgets (`<select>`, `<input />`, etc) - so you'll end-up reinventing the wheel.